# different part of where condition apply to different part of mdx queries

Tags: where-clause, mdx

I'm new in mdx, i have question about put two condition in where to apply in different part of mdx queries.
in my query i have two set(include from date:to date) that i want apply first set to first member and second set to second member but i don't want to create tuple in member because i want to calculate sum of measure for every customer.
when i put condition in where, just one date apply to member I want apply different condition apply to different member. 
how can I do this?

```
WITH 
SET BaseDate AS
  [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1396/02/22] :  [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1396/03/19]

SET CompareDate AS
    [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1396/01/21] :  [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1396/02/19]


MEMBER TotalCustomerCntInBase AS 
   Sum(BaseDate.item(count(BaseDate)-1) ,[Measures].[Total Customer Cnt])

MEMBER TotalCustomerCntInCompare AS 
   Sum(CompareDate.item(count(CompareDate)-1) ,[Measures].[Total Customer Cnt])


member numberOfActivecustomers as 
count(filter (nonempty([Vw Customer].[Customer BK].[Customer BK],[Measures].[Trade Cnt]),[Measures].[Trade Cnt]=1))

select {numberOfActivecustomers} on 0
from [DV Present]
where ([Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1395/01/01]:[Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1395/02/01])
```

Comment: What members you want to behave differently? It's not really clear from your code. You are using only the [numberOfActivecustomers] member here.

Comment: For clarification, consider the following code,
I want basedate apply to numberOfActivecustomers1 and CompareDate apply to numberOfActivecustomers2. and finally compare numberOfActivecustomers1 and numberOfActivecustomers2.

Comment: WITH 
SET BaseDate AS
  [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1396/02/22] :  [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1396/03/19]

SET CompareDate AS
    [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1396/01/21] :  [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1396/02/19]

member numberOfActivecustomers1 as 
count(filter (nonempty([Vw Customer].[Customer BK].[Customer BK],[Measures].[Trade Cnt]),[Measures].[Trade Cnt]=1))

Comment: member numberOfActivecustomers2 as 
count(filter (nonempty([Vw Customer].[Customer BK].[Customer BK],[Measures].[Trade Cnt]),[Measures].[Trade Cnt]=1))

select {numberOfActivecustomers} on 0
from [DV Present]
where (BaseDate,CompareDate)

Comment: I want calculate  a measure for different date to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sum days you may create two calculated members (periods) and run any measure against them:

```
With 
Member [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].[BaseDate] as
Sum(
    [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1396/02/22]:
    [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1396/03/19]
)

Member [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].[CompareDate] as
Sum(
    [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1396/01/21]:
    [Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].&[1396/02/19]
)

// Add here any calculations you need ...

Select 
{[Measures].[Trade Cnt]} on 0,
{[Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].[CompareDate],[Vw Dim Date].[Shamsi Date].[CompareDate]} on 1 
from [DV Present]
```